# Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.8) is greater than your local version (1.0.2)

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

```
C:\dev\myApp> ng serve -o 
Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.8) is greater than your local version (1.0.2). 
The local Angular CLI version is used.
To disable this warning use `"ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false"`
```

I don't know what to do with this.

I tried **uninstalling angular/cli and npm cache clean**  but still have problems.

Anyone help me !

Comment: This is just a warning. If you want to disbale such warning run this command in your terminal: ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false

Comment: Depending on the version of angular that you are using, this is not just a warning but will become a problem. @RachitShroff OP is using angular 6, with this config and suppressing the warning he wouldn't even know why his `ng update` command is failing for example. The correct way to fix this is to edit the package.json, edit @angular/cli's version to one that is supporting angular 6's features

Comment: @baao Agreed. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have the old angular/cli package in your package.json

To update use:

```
npm r angular-cli
npm i @angular/cli@latest -D
```

Be aware though, if you have already been using the old cli for a long time, you might have to do some code migration. Especially when it comes to tests, polyfills and the angular config file.

You could try to create an empty angular project using the new cli, and compare the files which are created there, with the files you have in your own project, and update where applicable.

After that, when you have to update your cli again, you can use the new `ng update` command

Comment: The problem is to run an old project with the old version while I have the latest version installed. I will try .. Thank you for the help

Comment: @takoua in that case, there is no problem. It's just a notice/warning which won't affect anthing

Answer (score 5):

You are using new project in older CLI  you need to run this commands

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

or you can try this approach

**Updating npm :**

```
Run [sudo] npm install -g npm  (sudo  is only required on Mac/ Linux)
```

**Updating the CLI :**

```
[sudo] npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli 

npm cache clean 

[sudo] npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

i have try all command above but, it don't work. Maybe you can try this command for same probblem. it work for me.

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install
```

if it still problem you can visit : https://angular.io/cli/update
and you can choice "Angular Update Guide" for specify version update from X to X